# How to optimize parameters of CART by using the genetic algorithm with R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, decision-tree

In order to train the support vector machine, we must determine various parameters.

For example, there are parameters such as cp and minsplit.

I am using cross validatio right now , to find these parameters, and I got cp=0.02.

Below is the code for that:

```
library(caTools)
set.seed(3000)
spl = sample.split(dat$Incident.Category, SplitRatio = 0.8)
Train = subset(dat, spl==TRUE)
Test = subset(dat, spl==FALSE)

library(caret)
library(e1071)

# Define cross-validation experiment
numFolds = trainControl( method = "cv", number = 10 )
cpGrid = expand.grid( .cp = seq(0.01,0.5,0.01)) 

train(Incident.Category ~ Working.Condition + Observation.Type +Injury.Potential.Score + Equipment.Damage.Score  + Safety.Standards + Incident.Type, data = Train, method = "rpart", trControl = numFolds, tuneGrid = cpGrid )

CartMOdel = rpart(Incident.Category ~ Working.Condition + Observation.Type + Injury.Potential.Score+ Equipment.Damage.Score  + Safety.Standards + Incident.Type,data = Train, method="class", cp = 0.02)
```

Now I want to know how to use GA to optimize these parameters.
My data is categorical, so I am also confused about how to choose the fitness function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a single parameter. It does not make sense to use a genetic algorithm.

Instead, grid search is appropriate.